# How to use the "cipher" command properly

Tags: windows, encryption, command

I am using the `cipher` command to encrypt a file so that nobody can read that. 
I tried this command : `cipher /e /a exp\test.txt`

I noticed the content of the file remained same. Only the file properties changed to encrypted. (Also the color of the filename changed to green. :P). I can still read, modify and delete the file.

Later I tried to decrypt: `cipher /d /a exp\test.txt`

The content as before same and in properties encrypted is unchecked.

I can read write and delete the file after encryption, what is the meaning of encryption then? How to use it properly? Am I missing something? Can anybody help me on this cipher command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cipher` command on Windows allows you to control the encryption of files/directories provided by the `Encrypting File System (EFS)`.

The important thing to note about EFS is that it is *transparent* encryption from the point of view of those granted access to the files. In other words, whilst the file data is encrypted *on disk*, providing you have keys to the file, you don't need to explicitly decrypt it in order to view the contents, it can just be read as any other file and the file system handles decrypting the data automatically. However, if you were to try and access the file as another user on the machine, or by reading data directly off the disk the file would be inaccessible.

You're not doing anything "wrong" here, it's just that `cipher` and EFS don't do what you expect them to.

Answer (score 2):

The file is indeed encrypted at the file system level. That is, it's encrypted on disk, but NFTS will automatically decrypt on behalf of any application that is attempting to read that file running under your account.

Copy the encrypted file to a shared (NTFS) disk directory and validate it's still green in explorer.  Then sign out and sign in with another account on this PC.  I don't think you'll be able to read the file.